# How to find y-intercept of a parallel line with a certain distance from another line

Tags: java, jpanel

I am using Java and a JPanel to draw a red line. The red line can have any slope and y-intercept, but both are calculated.

A yellow parallel line needs to be drawn 250px away from from the red line. How would one calculate the y-intercept of the yellow parallel line?

The following picture is an example of what the red and yellow lines could look like. Also since this is a JPanel, the origin is in the top left and the y values are all positive.

y-intercept diagram:

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

From the slope, you can compute the angle that the line has to the x-axis, as

```
double angleRad = Math.atan(slope);
```

This is also the angle at the `0,??` corner of the little triangle in your image (the angle that you painted in gray is a right angle).

Recalling that

```
         side adjacent to angle a
cos(a) = -------------------------
              hypotenuse
```

and given that you have the desired length of the side adjacent to angle a (namely, the length of your blue line, which should be 250), you can compute the length of the hypotenuse as

```
hypotenuse = 250 / cos(a)
```

which is basically how much you have to shift the red line in (negative)  y-direction to obtain the yellow line. Note that this will obviously approach infinity when the angle approaches 90°....

An MCVE, for a quick test:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ParallelLineInterceptTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ParallelLineInterceptTestPanel p = new ParallelLineInterceptTestPanel();
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));

        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("slope: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        JSlider slopeSlider = new JSlider(0, 1000, 50);
        slopeSlider.addChangeListener(e -> 
        {
            int slopeValue = slopeSlider.getValue();
            p.setSlope(slopeValue / 100.0);
        });
        controlPanel.add(slopeSlider);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(1200,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class ParallelLineInterceptTestPanel extends JPanel
{
    private double slope;
    private double yIntercept;

    public ParallelLineInterceptTestPanel()
    {
        this.slope = 0.5;
        this.yIntercept = 500;
    }

    public void setSlope(double slope)
    {
        this.slope = slope;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double x0 = 0;
        double y0 = yIntercept;
        double x1 = getWidth();
        double y1 = y0 + slope * getWidth();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0, y0, x1, y1));

        double distance = 250.0;
        double angleRad = Math.atan(slope);
        double offsetY = distance / Math.cos(angleRad);
        double px0 = x0;
        double py0 = y0 - offsetY;
        double px1 = x1;
        double py1 = y1 - offsetY;

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(px0, py0, px1, py1));


    }
}
```